# Center the image in PHP

Tags: php

i have this code. how i can make the image be at the center and the text make it more bigger?

```
if ($spell_checker->check_word($_GET['wordtext'])) {
    echo '<img src="images/betul.jpg" width="100" height="100" >'.'<br />';
    echo 'Tahniah, Ejaan Anda Tepat Sekali!';
}
else {
    echo '<img src="images/salah.jpg" width="100" height="100">'.'<br />';
    echo 'Opss.Ejaan Yang Betul Ialah: ';
    print_r(implode($spell_checker->suggest($_GET['wordtext'])));
}
```

Comment: PHP is a server side language that does not control anything about your page style directly. Search and read about HTML and CSS.

Comment: but as for the image size, it work well..i can play around with width and height of the image..but when i want to make it center, it doesnt work..

Comment: The image size in your case has notihng to do with PHP. Is still is HTML (PHP is only outputing it). First of all you should separate your PHP code from the HTML output (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html), and then use HTML and CSS as Guilherme pointed.